# If $t^\alpha f(t)$ is bounded for all $0<\alpha<1$, does it follow that $f$ is integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Suppose we have a (continuous) function $f: (0,1) \to [0,\infty)$ that satisfies for all $\alpha \in (0,1)$ that $\sup_{t \in (0,1)} t^{\alpha} f(t) < \infty$. Does it then follow that $f$ (which is the monotone pointwise limit of the functions $t^{\alpha} f(t)$ as $\alpha \to 0$) is integrable, i.e. that
$$ \int_0^1 f(t) \, dt < \infty? $$

Thank you for your time.

Comment: $|f(t)|\leq M t^{-1/2}$ and $\int_0^1 t^{-1/2}\,dt<\infty$.

Comment: Thank you, I don‘t know how I missed that…

Comment: I've convert the comment to an answer, so you can accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any fixed $\alpha\in(0,1)$, since $\sup_{t \in (0,1)} t^{\alpha} f(t) < \infty$, we can find $M$ such that
$$0\le t^\alpha f(t)\le M \text{ for all }t\in(0,1),$$
which means that
$$0\leq f(t)\leq Mt^{-\alpha}\text{ for all }t\in(0,1).$$
Now, since $\int_0^1 t^{-\alpha}\,dt<\infty$   for any $\alpha\in(0,1)$, we know that
$$\int_0^1 f(t)\,dt<\infty.$$

**Remark.** As the proof shows, to get the integrability of $f$, you only need $\sup_{t \in (0,1)} t^{\alpha} f(t) < \infty$ for only one $\alpha\in(0,1)$.